# Which version of the C Standard Library does the C++23 Standard incorporate?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, standards, c++23

(My original question was going to be about "What happened to `_BitInt`?" but that was based on a misreading of some cppreference pages).

The Library Introduction section 16.2 of the C++23 Draft Standard says that the C Standard library is supported in C++.  The only reference to a specific C standard, however, is in a footnote (#141) in 16.3.  This is  to the 2018 C Standard, which doesn't mention `_BitInt`.  But I found a description of `_BitInt` in the draft C 23 Standard.

Does the C++23 Standard incorporate a specific version of the C Standard Library?

- If so, which one?
- If not, is there a mechanism to incorporate the libraries of future C Standards?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you are asking. Your link to `cppreference` deals with **C**23, and the `Wikipedia` articles deals with **C++**23, and I cannot find any reference to `_BitInt` in that page. Am I missing something?

Comment: Should that be "claim that **C23** adds", not C++23?

Comment: This is from the draft C++ Standard [\[defns.c.lib\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/defns.c.lib) _"...library described in ISO/IEC 9899:2018, Clause 7..."_ - you would now need to reference the ISO number to the C Standard.

Comment: @RichardCritten I think that qualifies as an answer

Comment: @Brian61354270 - it's from the draft and I don't yet have the C Standard from ISO ... trying to fill in the blanks.

Comment: @RichardCritten It's C17: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/projects.html :)

Comment: @Erel Good catch.

Comment: It's very unlikely that such a thing makes it to ISO C++ as a core feature. Compare the `complex` C keyword with `std::complex` template in C++ as an example. If C++ is going to adopt such a feature,  it would be a library template, and the reference implementation has been present since 2 decades. Currently anyone can include **Boost.multi_precision** in their projects: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints.html Note that floating point and fixed point counter parts are present. There are a tone of C++ numeric libraries around.

Comment: Since when did C++ incorporate versions of the C library?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It's those damn cyberpunk megacorps. They incorporate EVERYTHING.

Comment: `_BitInt` is a core feature of C23, not part of its standard library.  You will not get it in C++ by virtue of incorporation of any version of the C standard library.  There are other C language features that do not appear in C++, too.  VLAs, for example.  C++ is not a superset of C.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quoting [N4950 2.2](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/n4950.pdf) (the final working draft of the C++23 standard):

> 2. The library described in ISO/IEC 9899:2018, Clause 7, is hereinafter called the C standard library<sup>3</sup>.
>
> <sup>3</sup> With the qualifications noted in Clause 17 through Clause 33 and in C.7, the C standard library is a subset of the C++
> standard library

where [ISO/IEC 9899:2018 is the C17 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C17_(C_standard_revision)).

Note while the C++23 standard names a specific C standard library version, it is still possible for an implementation to provide *any* additional features as language extensions. That could include support for later versions of the C standard library or support for C core language features (like `_BitInt(N)`). For example, both GCC and Clang provide [C99 VLAs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/11082165) as a language extension when compiling C++ code, and Clang [supports C23's `_BitInt(N)` as an extension](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#extended-integer-types) when compiling C++ code or C code for earlier editions.

Answer (score 5):

You've misread cppreference, which despite the name is also a reference for C. The page you link describes the C23 standard, so it makes sense for it to list things added in that standard. The wikipedia page  you link is for C++23, but it doesn't mention `_BitInt`.